# Best way to combine these results using Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have multiple result sets (they are in fact result of inline views) each of which provides DIFFERENT attributes and I want to combine them together on two IDs. What is the most efficient way to do this using Oracle SQL?

I dont think I can just use UNION because then I would get multiple rows with same two IDs and the attributes spread out between them - I want all rows with same tow IDs to COLLAPSE into one row.

Example:

Table A:

```
MAIN_ID  SUB_ID  ATTRIB_A   ATTRIB_B
1        100     100        Red
1        101     150        Green
2        300     125        Orange
```

Table B:

```
MAIN_ID  SUB_ID  ATTRIB_C   ATTRIB_D
1        101     High       25
2        120     Medium     10
2        300     Low        20
```

I want to write a query where the result set looks like this:

```
MAIN_ID  SUB_ID  ATTRIB_A   ATTRIB_B   ATTRIB_C   ATTRIB_D
1        100     100        Red        <NULL>     <NULL>
1        101     150        Green      High       25
2        120     <NULL>     <NULL>     Medium     10
2        300     125        Orange     Low        20
```

But how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a full outer join:

```
select coalesce(a.main_id, b.main_id) as main_id,
       coalesce(a.sub_id, b.sub_id) as sub_id,
       a.attrib_a, a.attrib_b, b.attrib_c, b.attrib_c
from tableA a full outer join
     tableB b
     on a.main_id = b.main_id and a.sub_id = b.sub_id;
```

Comment: Ah yes, thanks! I think the trick was I was missing the coalesce so my results when trying to use outer join looked wrong! That makes it work perfectly!